# YouTube iframe api (existing iframe); Cannot get iframe-api to work

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am making a "video cycler" which will allow us to have multiple videos on one website; but only have one of them large. The plan was to have them "auto cycle" when the video is finished playing. I was going to use the onStateChange feature to figure out when I should cycle them. All is going well expect for the fact that I cannot seem to get the api to work.

(using a different videoID because the real video isn't public yet)

HTML:

```
<iframe id="video0" width="640" height="385" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dREeDjQ0jIg?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=*" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

JavaScript:

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    video = document.getElementById('video0');
    player = new YT.Player(video, {
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        })
    }
function onPlayerReady(e) {
    console.log("hey Im ready");
    }
function onPlayerStateChange(e) {
    console.log(e)
    }
```

Log: 
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I stole your code and it worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help @SeanKendle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that my issue was <del>the a combo of the video not being public and</del> not having my server in the

```
&origin=SERVER_URL/IP
```

I listed out the full path to my file (it was a local server, so I did some port forwarding).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any problem with the iframe  ! since the real video is not public yet error 404 is what you can expect !

Comment: Alright, I will try loading it with that test video.

Comment: for a sample,check it out with some other video that is already there in youtube !