# Access youtube API with exist Iframe (using share on the youtube video website)

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

How can I access youtube API with exist Iframe (using share on the youtube video website) my code: 
 `<iframe id="welcome" width="100%" height="100%" src="SomeUrl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="player"></iframe>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Examples):

> Requirements
>
> The user's browser must support the HTML5 **`postMessage`** feature.
>   Most modern browsers support **`postMessage`**, though Internet
>   Explorer 7 does not support it.
>
> Embedded players must have a viewport that is at least 200px by 200px.
>   If the player displays controls, it must be large enough to fully
>   display the controls without shrinking the viewport below the minimum
>   size. We recommend 16:9 players be at least 480 pixels wide and 270
>   pixels tall.
>
> Any web page that uses the IFrame API must also implement the
>   following JavaScript function:
>
> - **`onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`** – The API will call this function when the page has finished downloading the JavaScript for the player
>     API, which enables you to then use the API on your page. Thus, this
>     function might create the player objects that you want to display when
>     the page loads.

[Examples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) were also given to start with.

You can also take this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668815/youtube-iframe-api-existing-iframe-cannot-get-iframe-api-to-work) as a reference.

The JavaScript here works.

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    video = document.getElementById('video0');
    player = new YT.Player(video, {
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        })
    }
function onPlayerReady(e) {
    console.log("hey Im ready");
    }
function onPlayerStateChange(e) {
    console.log(e)
    }
```